# Weird Error Building TMX Maps

Tags: c#, monogame, monogame-extended

I'm getting an error while build a tmx map using MonoGame Extended (see picture). By the looks of it, the importer can't find the tileset, which is weird.

- In my Map.tmx file the source for the tileset is ../Tilesets/Tileset.png. The tileset is placed in a Tilesets folder in the content pipeline, and the map lies in a Maps folder, so it should work, but it doesn't? I get the same error if I place the Tileset.png in the same folder as Map.tmx and change source to just Tileset.png.

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: There's not really enough info in your question to answer this. My first hunch is that there might be another file in your content that has the same name as the tileset? It could be a filename clash in MonoGame. If it's an issue with MonoGame.Extended, please raise a bug report [on github](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/issues)

Comment: When you open your TMX file with a text editor, what does the `<image>` tag say regarding the `source` of the tileset? What's the directory where your application is executed? Where is the actual tileset image file located?